# Differentiate multiple USB devices having same Vendor and Product ID

Tags: usb, lsusb

I am writing an application which allows a Linux machine to connect to internet over usb modem. I have multiple usb modems having same vendor and product ID; I cannot differentiate them using `lsusb` which gives vendor and product ID. Also giving IDs according to their usb ports does not solve my problem either, because I want to be able to use usb modems in whichever port I want.
Is there a unique identifier which I can use to differentiate my usb devices?

Comment: Do they have a MAC address?  This might show in ifconfig when they are operational; if it's constant across connect/disconnect cycles (or especially when moved to another machine) it's probably a real value in the hardware.

Comment: no they do not have mac address

Comment: try also the serial number, an USB device should have: PID, VID and serial number

Comment: @deniz that is very surprising, or is this a telephony modem rather than a mobile network interface?

Comment: you can think of it as a usb memory too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using serial numbers I differetiated my usb modems. Here in this site basic commands are shown.

http://wiki.openmoko.org/wiki/Hardware:AT_Commands#Section_5.2C_General_Commands

I used "ATE+CGSN" command which gives serial number of the device.